# Image saving in database from jLabel

Tags: java

I have write the code below. I can choose image using FileChooser clicking button a button(jButton5) on a Label(jLabel4). Now I want to save the imagePath in database clicking another button(jButton1). Which code should I write for jButton1.
Someone please help me.

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {                                         

    JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
    fc.showOpenDialog(this);
    File f=fc.getSelectedFile();
    String path=f.getAbsolutePath();
   jLabel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));

}                                        


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   


}
```

Comment: Tip : It's good to save the image path in database rather than storing the image.

Comment: Now if you want to ignore above **tip**, have you made connection to database?

Comment: Yes. I have made connection to database. How can I save image path in database? please.......

Comment: Take a look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store file location into database

1. Upload the file to some location.
2. Get uploaded file path
3. store that file path into some table.

---

If you want to store Images directly into Databse

1. Create table like below (MySql)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `IMAGES` ( 
> `ID` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
> `IMAGE` LONGBLOB NOT NULL, 
> PRIMARY KEY(`ID`) 
> )
> TYPE = InnoDB;
> ```

1. In your actionlistener

   ```
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   InputStream is = null;
   try {

       con = // get your database connection
       ps = con.prepareCall("insert into IMAGES values (?)");
       is = new FileInputStream(new File("file path"));
       ps.setBinaryStream(1, is);
       int count = ps.executeUpdate();

   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {        
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (SQLException e) {           
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();
   } finally{
       try{
           if(is != null) is.close();
           if(ps != null) ps.close();
           if(con != null) con.close();
       } catch(Exception ex){}
   }
   ```